# does rtk-query fetches requests in parallel?

Tags: reactjs, rtk-query

How can I fetch multiples requests in parallel/concurrent?

In javascript we can use Promise.all() but when we are using react + rtk-query how can we fetch requests in parallel?

For example, react-query has this https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/parallel-queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it does. If you write two `useSomeQuery` hooks in a component, if you don't manually stagger those with `skip`, they will happen at the same time.